# Export attribute table from ArcGIS Online and format it in Google Sheet/Excel Online etc

Tags: modelbuilder, attribute-table, arcgis-online, feature-layer

Some background:

I'm using Esri's Modelbuilder to produce some data from a view I've created in Microsoft SQL Server. I open the result from running the model in ArcGIS desktop and publish as a feature layer to ArcGIS online. I use that feature layer to feed a number of web maps, apps etc in ArcGIS online so that when I rerun the model and update the feature layer online, (as I do weekly-ish) my maps and apps update as well.

Many of the relevant users of this data would prefer to simply view a table but are not savvy enough to open the attribute table and find their rows/columns of interest so I'm looking for a way to automatically export SOME of that information AND be able to format the document in way that's consumable online. Ideally someone would be able to access our website and choose to either view the map or view a (formatted) table of the same data and BOTH would be updated when I re-publish/update the feature layer.

My thoughts on possible solutions:

1. Someone with saavy in writing scripts could probably do this but I do not possess that saavy unfortunately.
2. If I could have ArcGIS online automatically output its attribute table (unformatted) into Google Sheet/Excel Online I could produce a different formatted version with references to the source data created by ArcGIS Online, but I don't know how to achieve the first part.